# html5 cache manifest doesn't work in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, offline-caching, manifest.cache

I'm having strange issue - I was trying to get cache manifest working, but It didn't load any files properly after reloading page - finally I decided to find working demo, but... found demo also doesn't work...

Is there anything wrong with [this demo](http://html5demos.com/offlineapp), or there's just something wrong with my Chrome and Chromium. I'm getting error `Pending` on cached files and images are not displayed.

I've also noticed that Firefox asks if I allow page to use offline storage, when Chrome/Chromium doesn't.

Comment: Similar problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: um... it depends. * seems to not work especially well, the only thing I could get working is static list of cached files and fallback file. Network section in fact doesn't really prevent caching. My app is strongly driven by js so I'm just manually caching more dynamic files with IDB and for non-cached files I'm using headers and random dust at the end of url to fool browser. dealing with manifest sux a bit, so using js seemed to be way easier to me. But if you're asking strictly for manifest * issue - no I didn't find anything. here's my manifest [link](http://www.wubz.in/c.manifest)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Chrome won't prompt you, so that part is working as expected.
I notice that some of the images are included in the HTML with an absolute URL (for example, http://www.w3.org/html/logo/badge/html5-badge-h-connectivity-device-graphics-multimedia-performance-semantics-storage.png), but not included in the manifest file. So you may be relying on the browser cache for those.
Can you also try the demo on appcachefacts.info? See: http://appcachefacts.info/demo/ 
Does that work for you?
Note: To start fresh, you can wipe out your old caches under chrome://appcache-internals/

Comment: I made working manifest with listed all files manually, however `*` seems to not work. I've tried manifest like:

`CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
CACHE:
imgs/*.png`

but none of pngs inside imgs directory is loaded from cache then